# How can I use an android.net uri to be used as a source for the MediaPlayer class in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, objectdatasource

I have tried to use the GetItemAtId method. However when I set the data source of the music that should be played it returns an error.

```
void MediaListView_ItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //var selectedFromList = mediaListView.GetItemIdAtPosition (e.Position);
        var selectedFromList = songList.GetItemId(position: e.Position);
        string stringSong = selectedFromList.ToString ();
        Android.Net.Uri musicUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse (stringSong);
        string path = musicUri.ToString();
        //mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.Create (this, musicUri);
        //mediaPlayer.Start ();
        //var chosenSong = ;
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
        mediaPlayer.SetDataSource (path);
        mediaPlayer.Prepare ();
        mediaPlayer.Start ();
```

In the code sample I am trying to get the media player to start when an element in the list view is clicked. When I run this it returns an error at the line :
"mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(path);". The variable path is the position of the element clicked in the list view which is converted from a long to a string and is then converted to a Uri which is then converted to a string again as a different variable. I know this is not effective but it was the only way to convert the long to a string.

The error message says "SetDataSource invalid". Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Edit 1:
The Values for the songList is found using this:

```
private List<Song> myMediaManager()
    {
        List<Song> songsList;
        var uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
        string[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.AlbumId,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Title,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.InterfaceConsts.Artist,
        };
        var loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, null, null, null);
        var cursor = (ICursor)loader.LoadInBackground();
        songsList = new List<Song>();

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                songsList.Add(new Song
                    (
                        cursor.GetLong(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0])),
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])),
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2])),
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[3]))
                    ));
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }

        return songsList;
    }


}
```

The class Song holds the values for each track:

```
public class Song
{
    private long id;
    private String albumId;
    private String title;
    private String artist;

    public Song(long songID, String album, String songTitle, String songArtist)
    {
        id = songID;
        albumId = album;
        title = songTitle;
        artist = songArtist;
    }


    public long getID() { return id; }
    public string getAlbumId() { return albumId; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public String getArtist() { return artist; }
}
```

Edit 2
I had forgotten to show the other class thats involved in this here it is:

```
public class MusicTabActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;
    public string chosenSong; 
    ListView mediaListView;
    //List view for song list
    IList<Song> theSongs;
    //records of songs found sorted into an array
    MediaListAdapter songList;
    //song adapter
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.musicTabMain);

        //Variables for music items
        mediaListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mediaList);
        mediaListView.ItemClick += MediaListView_ItemClick;

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        //Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        Button mediaButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myMedia);

        //button.Click += delegate {
        //  button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        //};

        mediaButton.Click += delegate
        {
            //This will be the action that gets the list of music items

            //Get the list of music items
            theSongs = myMediaManager();

            //Create the adapter
            songList = new MediaListAdapter(this, theSongs);

            mediaListView.Adapter = songList;

        };
    }
```

And the code for the list adapter

```
public class MediaListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Song>
{
    Activity context = null;
    IList<Song> songs = new List<Song>();

    public MediaListAdapter(Activity context, IList<Song> songs) : base ()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.songs = songs;
    }

    public override Song this[int position]
    {
        get { return songs[position]; }
    }



    public override int Count
    {
        get { return songs.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var song = songs[position];

        var view = (convertView ?? 
            context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(
                Resource.Layout.SongDetail, 
                parent, 
                false)) as LinearLayout;

        var txtName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NameText);
        var txtArtistName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ArtistText);

        txtName.SetText (song.getTitle(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        txtArtistName.SetText(song.getArtist(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);

        return view;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly are the values of each stage of the conversion process?  It sounds like you are not ending up with a valid URI, either because you're staring with bad data, or something is going wrong at some step in the conversion process.

Comment: Initially the value of the position clicked in the list view (which is a long that passes an integer) is converted to a string to then be converted into a Uri.

Comment: I asked for exact values, not vague comments about their types.  Are you certain that the values you are dealing with are valid Android media URIs?

Comment: How can you not know the values of your own data?  Did songList just get created magically without any code?  Or did you create it and populate it with data?  Use the debugger or some Console.Writeline statements to determine what the values are.

Comment: Oh ok I wasn't sure what you meant but now I have edited the question. I have put the code for the values returned for songList.

Comment: Your Song class does not store the path of the song, and Song.ToString() will just return the name of the class, not the path.

Comment: Ok is there a way I can set the path of the song in the Song Class?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in the uri to the MediaPlayer like so:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, musicUri);
```

Refer to Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)).

Comment: I have tried passing the musicUri into the MediaPlayer but it returns an exception at that point "mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, musicUri);".

Answer (score 0):

Your Song class doesn't contain the URI of the song, and the ToString() method will return the name of the class, not the URI of the song.

If you have taken the time to step through your code in the debugger it would have been obvious that this was the case.  Learning to use the debugger is an important skill, and you should take the time to do it.  It will make you a much more effective programmer.

I *believe* the URI for a song is just the ID appended to the Media URI, so you should be able to get the URI doing something like this (untested):

```
public class Song
{
    // add this property to your Song class, other code should remain
    public Uri Uri { 
      get {
        return Android.Net.Uri.WithAppendedPath (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri, id.ToString());
      }
    }

}
```

then your Click handler can be modified to

```
void MediaListView_ItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var song = songList.GetItemId(position: e.Position);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
        mediaPlayer.SetDataSource (song.Uri);
        mediaPlayer.Prepare ();
        mediaPlayer.Start ();
    }
```

Comment: Most of it works except Uri.WithAppendedPath(Uri.WithAppendedPath (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri, id.ToString()); section brings up a compiler error "MediaBrowserService\MediaBrowserService\Song.cs(33,33): Error CS0176: Member 'Android.Net.Uri.WithAppendedPath(Android.Net.Uri, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead (CS0176) (MotorVator)

Comment: I have changed it to what you have edited but I cannot use mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(sing.Uri). I think this is because I am using the GetItemId method from the List Adapter I have made a second edit in the question

Comment: Also the compiler error says that I cannot convert a long to Java.FileDiscriptor

Comment: I assumed that songList was a List<Song>.  You may need to adjust the code so that "song" is the selected song.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, by using the get method in the Song class I was able to pass the song's uri by adding this to the click event

```
void MediaListView_ItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var song = songList[e.Position];
    var songUri = song.Uri
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.SetAudioStreamType (Stream.Music);
    mediaPlayer.SetDataSource (this, songUri);
    mediaPlayer.Prepare ();
    mediaPlayer.Start ();
}
```